# woocommerce override of product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with the following code when I make the price variable the function doesn't work but when I hardcode a price it works. (note I am in a testing face and haven't worried about security)

this, down't work:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_obj ) {
    global $product, $woocommerce ,$wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_POST['fra'] ) ){
        $GLOBALS['$_fra'] = urldecode( $_POST["fra"] );
    } else {
        $GLOBALS['$_fra'] = "";
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['til'] ) ){
        $GLOBALS['$_til'] = urldecode($_POST["til"]);
    } else {
        $GLOBALS['$_til'] = "";
    }
    if ( $GLOBALS['$_til'] !="" && $GLOBALS['$_fra'] !="" ){

        $t1 = urldecode( $GLOBALS['$_til'] );
        $t2 = urldecode( $GLOBALS['$_fra']);

        $objArray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $t1 FROM test_priser WHERE city = '$t2'");

        if ( isset($objArray[0]->$t1) ){
            $priser = explode("/",$objArray[0]->$t1);
            if ( !isset($priser[1]) ){
                $priser[1] = intval($priser[0]);
            }
        }

        echo "priser[1] = ".$priser[1]; //this outputs the expected value
    }

   if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ){
       return;
    }
    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->set_price( $priser[1] );
    }
 }
```

When I add this line, and override the variable, it works:

```
$priser[1] = 1000;
```

I am quite confused as to what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who might stumble upon this. Seems I need to pass the variable price in the session then it works.

you can find the answer here: [custom price on woocommerce product](http://sarkware.com/woocommerce-change-product-price-dynamically-while-adding-to-cart-without-using-plugins/)